# error TS2339 : Property '' does not exist on type '' Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

error TS2339: Property 'message' does not exist on type 'EmailData[]'

It's my code. Help me!

```
interface EmailData {
    message: string
}
function ParseJsonToObject(data:any){
  let obj:Array<EmailData>;
  for(var key in data.json()){ // {message: "Hello!"}
    obj[key] = JSON.stringify(data.json()[key]);
  }
  console.log("Data Check :: "+obj.message);
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: You have typed obj as an *array* of emails, arrays don't have a message property. Either that type is wrong, or you need to index into the array.

Comment: You should paste the content of data in you question to supplement your question. Use browser console to interrogate it and insert screenshot image. It's in the toolbar icon next to {} for code snippet. Just drag image onto prompt drop zone that appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear if you want to convert your JSON with type 'any' to a typed array regardless of the keys that it has, or do you want to filter out the messages in the JSON data?

This example shows how your 'any' data can become typed data:

```
interface EmailData {
    message: string
}

function parseJsonToObject(data:any):EmailData[]{
    let arr = new Array<EmailData>();
    for (let obj of data) {
        arr.push(<EmailData>obj);
    }
    return arr;
}


let test:any = [{ "message": "hello" }];
let result:EmailData[] = parseJsonToObject(test);
console.log(result[0].message);
```

Comment: Thank you.!!  I was trying to add it dynamically as if it were an existing JavaScript.

Comment: Are there any associative arrays in the type script??

Comment: Object was unable to use Interface, so Array was used. Why is Object Unavailable Interface

Comment: You can also convert non-typed objects to typed objects, but you have to be certain that your fetched data conforms to your interface. See https://jsfiddle.net/urwz8r6g/1/